# Подружить checkbox и player

Tags: javascript, html

Сделал на своём сайте чекбокс, который должен обрабатывать музыку. Т.е., если checkbox выключен, музыка не играет, если включен — играет. Но почему-то не получилось. Скажите, как поправить мой код?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="checkbox3" class="ios-toggle" />
<label for="checkbox3" class="checkbox-label" data-off="off" data-on="on"></label>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('checkbox3').checked =
    document.getElementById('checkbox3').onclick = function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            document.getElementById('player').start();
        } else {
            document.getElementById('player').stop();
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас синтаксис неправильный.

```
document.getElementById('checkbox3').checked = true;//Вангую
document.getElementById('checkbox3').onclick = function () {
    if (this.checked){
        document.getElementById('player').start();
    }else{
        document.getElementById('player').stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот блин, а я даже не написал check(), uncheck() функции, из за этого и косяк! 
Где их будет логичнее всего объявить?

Comment: А что они будут делать?

Comment: Так да , они не нужны. Я перепутал.
Но, почему-то, даже исправленный вариант не реагирует на функции внутри условий.

Comment: А что за элемент у вас c id='player'? Попробуйте `play` и `pause` вместо `start` и `stop`

Comment: Конечно же! У меня не правильно определены функции в этом элементе. Поправил - всё заработало.